# How to make mysql accept date in a particular format from a migration page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of excel sheets which I will be uploading to the database; with date in the format 05-Sep-2019. Is there a way to make mysql recognize it as a date rather than a string? I can use replace in excel to replace '-' with '/' if '-' doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **strtotime** function of php and format as you want

```
$date = '05-Sep-2019';
$newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date)); //2019-09-05
$newdate = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($date)); //2019/09/05
$newdate = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date)); //05/09/2019
```

Or in Mysql

Kindly Note that MySQL stores date in YYYY-MM-DD format by default.

One way is to convert all dates into YYYY-MM-DD format so that it will be compatible with MYSQL.

We can format the date column in excel before exporting it to MYSQL by following the below steps:

1. Select the column which contains the date
2. Right click and select **format cells**

   - Choose **date** under **category**(on left-hand side)
   - Then **choose** custom under category
   - Under **type** insert the format --> **YYYY-MM-DD**

You will see all the dates in the columns get converted into the format --> YYYY-MM-DD
Then you can import the date into MYSQL safely.

Another way is to keep the column datatype as VARCHAR and use TO_DATE() function to parse the string data into DATE format.

Comment: I have the dates in excel sheets. There are thousands of them. I will be uploading them via import in mysql. I cannot do that individually.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143764/mysql-reads-date-columns-in-excel-as-datetime have you tried this?

Comment: You tagged this as a PHP question, so you get a PHP answer. You can read the files with PHP and change the date. After this you can Insert it in your table

Comment: Agreed @MThiele That's why I given a solution in php.

Comment: Sorry about that. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it into Y-m-d format

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($your_excel_date)) // 2019-08-29
$date = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($your_excel_date)) // 2019/08/29
```